# How to use properly pseudo classes ::before and ::after without comprimising the position of the text

Tags: css

When CSS renders the quotation mark in the first case are too high (the problem is not margin or padding) when `display: block`, otherwise the first verse is pushed to the right to make room for the mark.
Ideally I would like to have the first quotation mark just above the first verse, with a small indent of all the 4 verses equally balanced.

```css
.incipit::before{
    content: '“';
    color: #B42B51;
    font-size: 4rem;
    display: block;

}


.explicit::after{
    content: '„';
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #B42B51;
```

```html
<li class = "incipit">This is the first verse</li>
<li>This is the second verse</li>
<li>This is the third verse</li>
<li class = "explicit">This is the last verse</li>
```

Comment: If you want all lines equally moved, you'd probably need add the quotes to the parent box instead.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet gives the pseudo elements absolute positioning and their 'parent' elements relative positioning. This means you can move the quotes around as you want without affecting anything else.

I am not absolutely sure what position you want the quotes to be in but you can change them by changing the top/left or the amount translated (in the case of the final quote which has to be raised up given it is sort of a subscript).

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 4rem;
}

.incipit,
.explicit {
  position: relative;
}

.incipit::before {
  content: '“';
  color: #B42B51;
  font-size: 4rem;
  display: inline-block;
  left: -2rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5rem;
}

.explicit::after {
  content: '„';
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #B42B51;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-60%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="incipit">This is the first verse</li>
  <li>This is the second verse</li>
  <li>This is the third verse</li>
  <li class="explicit">This is the last verse</li>
</ul>
```